How to introduce oneself in an job interview?
From a YouTube channel, I learned that during an introduction instead of saying "Myself (name)" one should say "My name is (name)." Though I do not consider the latter one wrong, I do not see any problem with the former word. Please explain.

You certainly don't say "Myself John Smith" (if your name is John Smith). There are many ways of introducing yourself ("Hello, I'm John Smith", "My name is John Smith", and you may be expected to say more than that...). "Myself John" is close to "Me Tarzan" which is the canonically bad way of introducing yourself.

"Myself Krishn Pandey" is completely the wrong way to introduce yourself. It's completely ungrammatical and no fluent speaker would say it.
The two most common ways of introducing yourself are:

I am Krishn Pandey

and

My name is Krishn Pandey.

